# How do laptops turn themselves off after shutdown?

Tags: power-supply

Since there's no ATX in a laptop, how are laptops turned off after shutdown, and what part of the laptop is responsible for doing so?

Comment: "Shutdown" is a Windows command that shuts down a computer (desktop or laptop). Linux (Kali and Ubuntu) also have "shutdown" commands that do the same thing. I am sure Power Management plays a part in this.

Comment: The processor is responsible for putting the device into S5 power state.  All x86 processors, which is any Intel or AMD processor, supports this particular state.

Comment: The answer below goes into detail what I am referring to exactly.  I don’t feel like explaining such a basic concept.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Something that's equivalent to the green wire in an ATX PSU. Not the ACPI BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

The high level concept is exactly the same in desktops and laptops.

There exists a small processor/microcontroller/circuit that uses very little power and works on standby supply (desktop) or with the battery (laptop). This MCU can be a separate chip or built-in to the chipset. This MCU is never shut down (unless power is completely gone), and it will detect if you push the power button and then it turns the main power supplies on and the main CPU starts running the BIOS/bootloaders/OS/etc.

When you tell an OS to shut down, it does so, and when everything that the OS must do before cutting power is done, the OS calls the BIOS ACPI power interface with a message that requests the computer to shut down and the main CPU halts operating. This message then goes to the low power MCU and it will turn off the main supplies.

Comment: Is that MCU responsible for power built into the motherboard in a laptop? In a desktop the power supply itself is responsible for turning itself off.

Comment: @user1477539 Yes in a laptop. And no the desptop power supply is not responsble for turning itself off - it has two parts. It has an always-on standby supply (ATX purple wire) that powers up the necessary portion of the motherboard to be able to detect power button or Wake-on-LAN etc. The motherboard will control the power supply to turn the main supplies on or off (ATX  green wire). The mothrboard parts that are always powered by mains input control the rest of the supply.

Comment: What is the equivalent of the green ATX wire on a laptop?

Comment: @user1477539 A piece of wire on printed circuit board. Or multiple wires. It does not matter what it actually is. The point is the layer of abstraction, there is a small thing that stays powered and it can turn on and off a much bigger thing. Same thing in your your TV, it has standby power section and main power section, and there is something in there that listens to remote control buttons and can turn main power on or off when requested. Or your car that has a computer to turn the engine off when you stop in red lights, and starts the engine when you release brakes again.